# How CMake detects the MSVC version

Tags: visual-studio, cmake

I have two MSVC versions installed: **Visual Studio 15 2017** and **Visual Studio 14 2015** on my system. When I run `cmake` on my project root directory, it detects the **Visual Studio 15 2017** version and creates a Visual Studio solution according to that but when I specify **Visual Studio 14 2015** using the command `cmake -G "visual studio 14 2015"`, it creates the solution according to this version.

But in my build environment or machine I am not installing the software but map the **complete installed software** at a central drive and set the environment variable using `vcvarsall.bat` and use it.

But now I am creating the infra using `cmake` in that it does not detect the MSVC version just by setting the path variable using the above way.

So does **CMake** configure by reading the **Registry** or an **environment variable**?

If it’s doing configuration using an **environment variable**, then what mistake I am doing?

If it’s doing configuration using the **Registry**, then how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Running `cmake.exe` in the console initialized with `vcvarsall.bat` should result in finding correct MSVC version.

Comment: @arrowd not in my case i am coping msvc to d: drive and run the vcvarsall.bat from their and its not taking this compiler but taking the latest compiler while running cmake . command

Comment: @arrowd does i have to pass the -G " " version after running vcvarsall.bat file or only cmake works fine

Comment: What i Observe that cmake always run the latest compiler that installed on your system what ever version i.e. lowest version vsvarsall.bat file you run it always build the solution for the latest msvc version . for building for lowest version you have to specify it using -G " " flag while running cmake command . so from above statement i conclude that it read the registry at the configuration time not the path variable.